# PHP filter(sanitize) $_GET to use in mysqli query?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

What would be the best or right way to get the value from the url using $_GET['id'] and to use it in a mysqli query?

Currently i'm using a regular expresion :

> $id = preg_replace('/{([a-zA-Z0-9]+)}/', '', $_GET['id']);

but I don't know if this is the right or best way to do this.

Please explain your answer.

Comment: if it work ,then is a good way to do it

Comment: @MariaGheorghe nonsense. `It it works` does not mean it works the right way

Comment: I need to check the passed value against the databse

Comment: Is your question about forgoing database escaping / parameter binding? (← Which would be easier!)

Comment: @MArchin you dnt need a special theniq to do such a simnple task , can be done in 1 milion ways

Comment: *"I need to check the passed value against the databse"* - I'm splitting hairs here; what's the real question, check if ID exists?

Comment: Simple or not, things should be done **right** way. Any shortcuts, especially driven by not understanding the problem in first place (which this question is good example of, hence preg_replace() or input_filter suggestions) are definitely bad and must be avoided.

Comment: I just need to check if this id(parameter) exists in the database before the script continues. I was only wondering if i'm getting the variable the right way to then use it in a mysqli string.

Comment: ...use `mysqli_num_rows()` or PDO's `rowCount()`. *I knew it*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reinventing the wheel. Depending on how you access db you may do not need do much (i.e. PDO will deal with this by itself) or use **proper** function to escape data, like [mysqli_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/pl/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

Answer (score 2):

If you are already using `mysqli` then you don't need to take the pains of sanitization in your hands for basic stuff. You can use prepared statements which will take care of those

```
if (isset($_GET["id"])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT abc FROM table WHERE id=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);   // or s if its a string
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

You can review examples here to find out how to deal with the result:

**[`get_result()` in PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php)**